# On Minecraft PE why is only one of my creative worlds NOT working?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why is only one of my creative worlds on Minecraft PE NOT working? It's really slow and the world won't generate fully, leaving holes all over the landscape! I have tried turning off my iPod to restarts the server and it didn't work.... What should I do?

Comment: I need your seed to see what I can do on Minecraft PE

Answer (score 1):

You could have a corrupted save. Although rare, this has been known to happen for no apparent reason and will only effect the corrupted world. The more likely possibility is that the save is just really laggy. This would explain all the holes that refuse to render.